# Does the HTTP spec allow returning different Content-Types for similar/identical requests?

Tags: http, swagger, content-type

Is it okay according to the HTTP spec to have a request that (for example) does the following:

```
GET https://www.example.com/api/images/1 -> 200 OK, Content Type "image/png"
GET https://www.example.com/api/images/2 -> 404 NOT FOUND, Content Type "application/json"
```

We're having trouble with this in Swagger since you have to specify the Content-Type of the response before making the request, so I figured I'd ask whether what we want to do is even acceptable according to the HTTP spec before we continue digging into how it can be solved with Swagger

Comment: There's no requirement to return identical response from identical requests - let along ones to *completely different* URLs as you've shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine for an URL to return different HTTP status codes depending on the result of the request. It's also OK to return different media types, e.g. based on the `Accept` header (aka [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation)) or other conditions.

In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, your example can be described like this:

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      produces:
        - image/png
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A PNG file
          schema:
            type: file
        '404':
          description: Not Found
          schema:
            type: object
            # properties:
            # ...
```

OpenAPI 3.0 improves response definitions and lets you specify the media types for specific status codes:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A PNG image
          content:
            image/png:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
        '404':
          description: Not found
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                # properties:
                # ...
```